# Trying to write two tables with one to one relationship but the joinColumn comes up null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a form on a webpage that needs to be put into two different tables, appinfo and preferences. Both appinfo and preferences have an id that is autogenerated. appinfo also contains a foreign key to preferences call "preferenceid". I need the autogenerated id of the preferences table to be entered into this field using hibernate.

I've created two POJO's using SpringMVC and I'm trying to write them to the database.  The basic format is:

Preferences.java:

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="preferences")
public class Preferences implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int preferencesid;
    (Other variables with getters and setters)

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="preferencesid", referencedColumnName="preferenceid")
    private AppInfo ai;
    public AppInfo getAi() {
        return ai;
    }

    public void setAi(AppInfo ai) {
        this.ai = ai;
    }
```

AppInfo.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="appinfo")
public class AppInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "appuserid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="preferenceid", referencedColumnName="preferencesid")
    private Preferences p;
    (Other variables and getters and setters)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Preferences getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setP(Preferences p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
```

When I persist the data, Preferences works fine, it auto generates its id value.  But my AppInfo isn't properly getting the preferencesid; it only has null.  If I change the table to allow for nulls, both will insert with all the correct information except the preferencesid in the AppInfo table is now null.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear.  I have a form on a webpage that needs to be put into two different tables, appinfo and preferences.  Both appinfo and preferences have an id that is autogenerated.  appinfo also contains a foreign key to preferences call "preferenceid".  I need the autogenerated id of the preferences table to be entered into this field using hibernate.

Comment: Hi @MMX, put it on your question. It is where your update is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you want `AppInfo` to hold the foreign key for `Preferences` and `Preferences` don't need a foreign key to `AppInfo`, then 
change as follows.

Remove the mapping from Preferences

```
     @Entity
     @Table (name ="preferences")
     public class Preferences implements Serializable {

     //    @OneToOne(mappedBy)
     //    @JoinColumn(name="preferencesid", referencedColumnName="preferenceid")
     //    private AppInfo ai;
```

and specify the cascade type in `AppInfo`

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="appinfo")
public class AppInfo implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="preferenceid", referencedColumnName="preferencesid")
    private Preferences p;
```

If you want make it `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
then, when you need to save the instance as follows.

```
    AppInfo ai = new AppInfo();     
    Preferences p = new Preferences();

    ai.setP(p);     
    session.persist(ai);
```

if you set to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, then you can use `session.save(ai);`.

---

**Option 2**

If you want both the tables to hold a foreign key to each other, then 
change as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="appinfo")
public class AppInfo implements Serializable {
    ....
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="preferenceid")
    private Preferences p;



@Entity
@Table (name ="preferences")
public class Preferences implements Serializable {
    ....
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="appuserid")
    private AppInfo ai;
```

Change the cascade type to `CascadeType.All` if you want.
When you save the instances,

```
    AppInfo ai = new AppInfo();     
    Preferences p = new Preferences();

    ai.setP(p);     
    p.setAi(ai);

    session.persist(ai);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow that fixed it!  It looks like the big mistake I made was not having ai.setP(p);     
    session.persist(ai);  but rather session.persist(ai); session.persist(p).  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You also need the `cascade` property. I set it to `PERSIST` and that is why  I used `session.persist(ai)`. Read more about cascade types and you can use `session.save(ai)` if you use `ALL` cascade option or hibernate specific save or update cascade option.

Comment: Yes, I had tried with cascade before, but without setting p in ai, it didn't work.  Ill look into the different cascade types like you suggested, when I tried setting cascade, I had it set to ALL.  Again, thanks for your help

Comment: I have but due to me being new, it apparently wont show up until I have 15 reputation points?